# Como ativar os eventos no mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, eventos

Estou tentando ativar os [eventos](https://www.devmedia.com.br/quick-tips-habilitando-e-entendendo-events-no-mysql-parte-1/14018) do `mysql` 5.7, mas recebo um erro.

Para:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Recebo:

> 01:16:06  SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON Error Code: 1227. Access
>   denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this
>   operation 0,057 sec

Na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-privileges.html) diz que é preciso alterar os privilégios, mas tentei com:

```
GRANT EVENT ON *.* TO user;
```

Mas não afeta nenhuma linha, e continua o mesmo erro inicial (you need SUPER...) quando tento ativar.

Também já editei o arquivo `my.cfn` (o que seria ideal) e inclui dentro do [mysqld], como indicado [neste](https://www.devmedia.com.br/quick-tips-habilitando-e-entendendo-events-no-mysql-parte-1/14018) e em outros artigos:

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = ON;
```

Mas não muda nada. Alguma ideia?